# Mobile touch support -- In Closure-library

Tags: touch, mobile-website, javascript-framework, google-closure-library

I was just wondering if we have a specific library or framework built on the closure-library , which is specifically designed for touch devices(Android or Ipad). I already have my web-app using the closure-library, now want to maintain consistency for the mobile touch devices or tablets.

There are many other frameworks or plugins for other libraries like:
http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/  --  (Ext.js)
http://jqtouch.com/  --  (jquery)

Do we have something similar for the closure-library.
Can somebody please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the plain TOUCH events are already defined

```
/**
* Constants for event names.
* @enum {string}
*/
goog.events.EventType = {
    ...
    // WebKit touch events.
    TOUCHSTART: 'touchstart',
    TOUCHMOVE: 'touchmove',
    TOUCHEND: 'touchend',
    TOUCHCANCEL: 'touchcancel',

}
```

But there is no gesture-recognizer.

If you use the gestures Webkit(Safari) fires, you will have to create your own externs file.

https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/GestureEventClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/GestureEvent

Answer (score 1):

If you download the touch library from jQueryMobile's site. Just build jQueryMobile only with their touch library. Import that into your project. Then have a map like I did...

```
  var hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window;

  var humanEvents = {

    DOWN: (hasTouch) ? goog.events.EventType.TOUCHSTART : goog.events.EventType.MOUSEDOWN,
    OVER: (hasTouch) ? goog.events.EventType.TOUCHSTART : goog.events.EventType.MOUSEOVER,
    MOVE: (hasTouch) ? goog.events.EventType.TOUCHMOVE : goog.events.EventType.MOUSEMOVE,
    UP: (hasTouch) ? goog.events.EventType.TOUCHEND : goog.events.EventType.MOUSEUP,
    OUT: (hasTouch) ? goog.events.EventType.TOUCHEND : goog.events.EventType.MOUSEOUT,
    CLICK: (hasTouch) ? "tap" : goog.events.EventType.CLICK

  };
```